# How to commit to think like a winner, instead of playing for maximizing emotional comforts?

Tags: learning

I have a knowledge to execution gap problem.

I understand poker winners play to maximize their profits and are ready to do the uncomfortable things that losers are not willing to (For eg: setting aside ego and following bankroll discipline etc).

I can even give a lecture on what are those uncomfortable things one should do to become winner. I find myself unable to commit to these disciplined uncomfortable plays. It doesn't mean that I am lazy to work on this area or I don't care about winning, simply I just don't find enough motivation or drive to stay disciplined when rubber hits the road.

How can I tackle this no motivation for discipline but enough motivation to win paradox!?

If you are a winner what keeps your motivation high to escape this biological motivation to stay in comfort zone? Is there any techniques, practices to improve the motivation part of my mental game?

Thanks!

Comment: The "no motivation for discipline but enough motivation to win paradox" sounds a lot like "I really wish this game were easier to beat than it actually is."

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I am talking about avoiding tilts and staying disciplined and not following the plan despite knowing what should be the plan.

Comment: I can emphasize with this question. I love learning strategy of poker that applies to individual games, like learning about pot odds, bet sizing, outs, blockers, hand ranges etc. , but I have trouble with the meta game (bankroll management, table selection, analysing my own hand history, etc.). It's difficult to switch from a mindset of wanting to win every game and finish in the money in every tournament, to being able to accept short-term losses while playing for the long term gain.

Comment: It's difficult to be happy with your play when you make a good call, but lose to a bad beat, and it's difficult to be disappointed with yourself when you make a horrible call, but suck out and win a big pot. It's easy to justify a bad call, by having thoughts up like "it was a good call against their range, I just got unlucky", and it's difficult to know when the thought is actually accurate or heavily biased by your desire not to have made a bad play.

Comment: However I think the answer to this might lie more in psychology than anything else. It is about self-discipline, and there are ways you can work on and improve your self-discipline, but it's not easy to dedicate effort to improve your self-discipline when you don't have much in the first place.

Comment: There's no easy answer but it gets easier when you can _justify_ your play by a reasoning eg. i made this call because ... i raised there and fold because ... Tilt is produced by short term results although your general play must have long term horizon eg. I did this play because i know it's a long term EV+, regardless if i lost now. Make a good reasoning of a play and you'll be good